# Passing through airport security with autism

Tags: safety, airport-security, tips-and-tricks, accessibility, autism

I am a young adult with autism (Asperger's to be precise). While there are many resources on how to travel with kids with autism, resources on how to do so if you have it yourself are rare to nonexistent.

Anyway, I have a lot of trouble with security checks. The fact that I have to separate from my things (including my plush, which helps me in stressful situations), go through a scanner and pick up my things again before someone runs off with them completely stresses me out. I feel extremely pressured by the people behind me and it ends up being a very uncomfortable experience.

I have a couple countermeasures currently. I organise my bags at home, so I only need to take my laptop out. I make sure there is nothing in my pockets beforehand and I make sure I wear a 2 piece outfit. Nevertheless, it still is a terrible experience. Going through currently takes more energy from me than any other part of a trip. Is there anything I can do to make this a smoother experience?

I hold a Dutch passport. I frequently visit the UK and somewhat rarely (once or twice a year) other countries.

Comment: What country are you in? If US, I would strongly suggest you look into using/getting a KTN (known traveller's number) which has some perks possibly useful to you. You can find more information about this at the [TSA Pre-Check site](https://www.tsa.gov/tsa-precheck)

Comment: Netherlands. I frequently travel to the UK, and somewhat rarely to other places. Thank you though.

Comment: In the USA, at least, you can request to be screened in private. This would mean there isn't a long line behind you pressuring you to speed up, and you wouldn't be separated from your possessions for as long. I'd imagine something similar is available in many other countries, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: If you're just travelling from the Netherlands to the UK, then the easy fix is simply to avoid flying at all! Just book a combined [train+ferry+train ticket](http://seat61.com/Netherlands.htm#train+ferry), often for quite a bit less than a plane ticket, and have a much less stressful trip with no airport security queues required

Comment: I am Asperger and I have taken the train+ferry+train that Gagravarr mentioned.  Taking the ferry as a passenger is very peaceful.  The passenger ferry terminal was deserted, as almost all passengers travel by car.  Two bored passport controllers were waiting for us.  We did not get separated from our luggage at all (unlike at Eurostar, where they *do* have airline-style checks).  The only stressful bit was that the morning train from Harwich to London got extremely full as it approached London, and transiting through London is never fun, but depending on your destination you might not have to.

Comment: Also: I strongly hate flying. I travel by train whenever possible, even if it means 3 days on the train (for example, from northern Sweden to southern Spain, or from Toronto, ON to Jasper, AB in Canada).

Comment: @gerrit If you're not in a rush, you can break your journey. Get off in Colchester, go have a decent breakfast, then continue your journey into London after the rush hour has died down. Or even just have breakfast in the cafe at the station in Manningtree, which is nice but can get busy

Comment: I would guess that if you talk to an airport and explain your situation they might be able to make some accommodations for you - maybe put you in the priority line, or take you to a special screening area. I don't think they want there to be stressed people in the security area any more than you want to be one of them.

Comment: @DJClayworth not only "might", at least in the US and UK they MUST make accommodations. What these accommodations are and how much they help is another question ...

Comment: What is the plush made of and represent?

Comment: @StrongBad Do you have a source for that? A friend of mine tried to ask to be screened in private at LHR once, the answer from the duty manager was "either you are screened here or you don't get on the flight"

Comment: @gerrit, 3 days on the train? Is there even Wifi?

Comment: Just to let you know, as a young adult without autism, I also get stressed from separating with my things and plush too. Considering how fast my heart beats and how fidgety I get watching him go into the dark machine, It must be really terrifying to have that worsened by Autism. I prefer to place him prominently sitting up, so I can quickly spot him when he gets out the machine on the other end, and this reassures me a bit. You probably already do this, but if not it might help.

Comment: @Pacerier Some wifi on day trains, none on overnight trains I've seen, although there's usually electricity. For information-addicts, roaming will soon likely be prohibited within the EU so GPRS/3G/4G could work where available.  Personally I tend to read, watch films, and sleep at night, and watch the landscape at day.

Comment: @Calchas see my answer.

Comment: One small idea: Could you get access to the fast track? It's usually much less crowded and people there are much less rushing; it could be easier to explain that you want to be separated only for as short time as possible from your luggage.

Comment: Wearing slippers or slip-on shoes is one thing I do to ease US air security (which wants passengers to remove their shoes).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

I understand that logic doesn't always help in times of stress, but the first thing I want to assure you is that people are not going to run off with your things. This is something we all worry about but that essentially never happens. The folks who manage the checkpoint are monitoring and your things are not out there without you for more than a few seconds.

Second, you mention that your plush helps you. Could you procure a small square of plush fabric? You could keep this in your pocket - there's no requirement that your pockets be empty, merely that they be empty of metal. Fabric alone will not set off any detectors and you can put your hands in your pocket and calm yourself if you have to wait a moment before you go through the scanner.

Third, forget the people behind you. The pressure you feel is not really from them. You owe them no obligation. They are waiting, they have their own issues, but they will never say "great trip today, the guy in front of me in the security line was so quick!" What's more, if such a person existed, they would say that about **you** because you're not pulling things out of 4 different bags and pockets, having to go through the scanner twice because you left your keys in your pockets, and so on. You're already faster than most of the people in the line. You have no obligation to set some sort of land speed record by not hesitating, not waiting with your stuff (I do that), or just walking at the pace you prefer.

Fourth, reward yourself for completing this worst part of the journey. Whether it's an expensive coffee, a magazine, a bar of chocolate -- buy something fun and frivolous right after the security check. Something you wouldn't normally get yourself. The day may come when you're planning a trip and find yourself looking forward to that dark-chocolate-and-orange bar waiting for you on the other side of security.

Comment: " there's no requirement that your pockets be empty," - at US airports using terrahertz scanners, they are enforcing this as a requirement. Even receipts, hankerchiefs will result in you being sent back again. I don't think Schipol has these, and I've not seen UK security with these scanners being so insistent however.

Comment: In my experience with the nude o scopes if they show something is in your pocket (I had a single credit card in a pants pocket once) it is enough for you to take it out and show them, you don't have to go through again. Luckily I have a KTN now so the nude o scopes are no longer part of my process.

Comment: Also, they will usually let you hold small things in your hands (such as your passport) while in the scanner.

Comment: @called2voyage they will, but it may be based on whether they think your attachment to the item is reasonable - passport and glasses make more sense to them than a plush or a piece of fabric - and whether they think something could be concealed in the item. That's why I suggested fabric rather than something larger and stuffed.

Comment: @KateGregory Yes, if it were a small piece of fabric, I think a brief mention that it was for stress relief would suffice. Stress balls are common enough that I think it would be understood.

Comment: Pockets are made of fabric. If I had this problem, it would be worth it for me to choose the part of my outfit I will be always wearing (e.g. a "travel" pair of jeans) and have plush lining sewn into the pocket. Alteration tailors usually work with the customer's material anyway, so the OP will be able to visit a fabric store and choose the best texture for himself. In fact, it might be a good strategy to line all pockets on all clothing with plush fabric, to have the opportunity for unobtrusive soothing in unexpected situations, even outside of the airport context.

Comment: @CMaster, Kate Gregory: I would add that the millimeter scanners can also flag empty pockets if your clothes are made from thick fabric.  In my experience, this has happened with a pair of heavy wool cargo pants that I like to fly in when it's cold, and also with a heavy flannel shirt with patch pockets that have flap closures.

Comment: Passing through IDA recentley - no, it was not acceptable to have small things in a pocket. Receipts caused people to be sent around again. Anyone attempting to walk into the scanner holding anything was also sent back and told to put it through xray (this happened to several people with passports). I was able to convince them to examine but not x-ray my personal radiation dosimeter, but that still involved explaining the purpose to 3 members of staff, and having *them* take it "across the line" - in my hand was not OK.

Comment: On Schiphol they have scanners that do show you have something in your pockets, or even pockets made of more layers of fabric. I have been patted down a few times already just because of the double layers of fabric. But if you do not mind that, you are welcome to have a single item in your pockets. I have had a fabric hanky in my pocket at one occation and the guards checking did not mind, just patted me down.

Comment: _"but they will never say 'great trip today, the guy in front of me in the security line was so quick!'"_ Hehe I do actually think this sometimes when reflecting back upon my day of travel. Though because it's _so bloody rare_ you're generally right. :)

Comment: mmm dark chocolate and orange...

Comment: all US airports i've ever been to (lots and lots) require your pockets to be completely empty before going through screening. if they're not, they'll ask you to empty them, period. doesn't matter what's in them. you typically can hold small non-metal items in your hands like @called2voyage said, though. i always hold my passport and boarding pass when going through the scanner.

Comment: @CMaster:  perhaps you could persuade them to put you through the luggage X-ray, so that the dosimeter can go through and remain accurate ;-)

Comment: "reward yourself for completing this worst part of the journey" absolutely!

Comment: I do not know OP and I have never been diagnosed but I am dead certain to have some level of ASD. And I travel with a teddy bear (have him since 1988) and at least for me it's not the plush material but the stability and the emotions you feel towards that particular plushie. I can cope with the security pretty OK but it's a very bad experience, I remember vividly quite a few of them, it just etches into you like acid.

Comment: @chx is right. I'm comforted by my plush specifically, not a different one or fabric. I have two, a bird and a teddy. The bird is smaller and usually goes on travels with me. Nonetheless, I tried Kate's advice during the security check in LHS. The tray with my suitcase and my plush on got taken apart. I quickly explained the situation to the officer, who handed me the plush. He was very friendly and talked with me to figure out what caused the trigger. (It was the graphic card I bought in the US a few days before). Thanks a lot!

Comment: For what it's worth, while many of the security staff (especially in Schipol) seem very terse and business-like, if you just chat with them about a valid concern they tend to warm up immediately. You could probably get by with a quick, rehearsed explanation about how airports give you severe anxiety and the plush is your stress relief. It should be able to go through the scanner with you just fine, and the worst that I could imagine happening is they'd want to squeeze it to make sure there's nothing inside.

Comment: Another option might be to ask if you could take the plush through the scanner with you, and then have them reverse it into the X-ray machine -- that way you'd be on the other side of the X-ray machine, put it on the belt, and they'd back your plush into the machine while you could stand there and watch as they back it in (and probably still see it, if barely), then send it back out to you. You'd still be physically separated from it, but you'd at least have the comfort of knowing that someone on the other end of the machine isn't going to snatch it off the belt when it comes out.

Comment: Just saying: A US TV show put an iPad into their hand luggage, which promptly disappeared, and "Find my Phone" found it a few hours later at the home of an airport security person who somehow "accidentally" had taken it out of their luggage and taken home. They filmed everything after they heard of complaints about disappearances.

Comment: I have metal knees. I get sent through the millimeter scanner. It almost always has some areas it cannot clear, so they have to get a woman to pat me down. Meanwhile, my carry-on gets through the X-ray several minutes ahead of me. I have never had anything stolen in the process.

Comment: Could you develop the same sort of feeling for e.g. a favorite shirt as you have for your plush? Along the lines of "This is my power shirt. Nothing is going to disturb me while I am wearing it.". Then wear it for air travel.

Answer (score 48):

Whenever you're planning a journey, consider if you really have to fly.  I am Asperger myself, and I avoid flights (although not for the exact same reason as you).

Between The Netherlands and the United Kingdom, there is absolutely no need to fly.  There are three ferry links from The Netherlands to England: one to the south, one to the centre, and one to the north.  Taking the ferry as a passenger only is a very peaceful experience, as the terminals were built in an era of far more passenger travellers, and most travellers nowadays drive onto the ferry by car.  The times I've taken overnight ferries in Europe, passenger terminals were deserted to the level that I thought I must be at the wrong place.  While on the ferry, you can be in your private cabin (including daytime crossings), which is like a little hotel room, very private, with a TV and (quite slow) wifi.

If I stay on the same continent, I travel by train whenever possible, even if it means 3 days on the train (from northern Sweden to southern Spain, or from Toronto, ON to Jasper, AB in Canada). It's quite possible, if you have the money you can book fully private compartments on many sleeper trains.  There's a wealth of information from [The Man in Seat61](http://www.seat61.com/).

Note that *there are some trains with airline-style luggage checks*.  On the Eurostar, your luggage has to be scanned.  On many Spanish trains too, although you might be able to hold on to your plush.  People with more (recent) experience on Spanish trains may be able to comment on that.

Now, suppose that you're travelling to a place where travelling without flying is almost impossible (Australia, South America, sub-Saharan Africa) or extremely time-consuming and costly from Europe (east-Asia, North America).  In this case, I have little to add to [Kate's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/58656/2509).  It may get easier if you do it more frequently.

**Edit:** [StrongBads answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/58669/2509) reminded me of the [Autipas](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autipas).  It's a special card you can show to airport personnel (it was reportedly inspired by an incident with an aspie flightspotter on Schiphol Airport).  Personally I wouldn't like such a card, but perhaps you would.

Comment: -1. this doesn't answer the question. not sure why all the upvotes.

Comment: @sgroves, answers that attempt to solve the underlying problem, even if not directly answering the question as posed, are welcome across Stack Exchange sites.  For some questions, such an answer is the only good answer.  See discussion of xy problems: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  Not saying this question is an xy problem (as sometimes flying is preferable or necessary) but still suggesting alternatives to flying seems like helpful information solving the underlying problem.

Comment: @sgroves The final paragraph, edited in shortly before your comment, does propose a route to an answer.  I didn't expand on it because I personally do not like it.

Comment: It is a good answer in my case. I probably should consider taking the boat more often. It's a pleasant experience. The downside though: my trip to the UK by ship would take me 2 + 1 + 10 + 5 = 18 hours using the boat to Harwich and 2 + 1 + 1 = 4 hours taking the flight. I'm also not sure on the card. Is it an official thing?

Comment: @J.Constantine Yes, boat (or train) is slower than flight although it's somewhat mitigated if you travel by night.  I don't think the Autipas is official, it's produced by the Nederlandse Vereniging voor Autisme.  You might find opinions on experiences with it on Dutch asperger forums (I've lived outside The Netherlands since 2007, but I wouldn't get one even if I didn't, because I fear it would just draw attention and enhanced stigmatisation; others disagree).

Comment: I've started [a question on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287458/is-the-term-aspie-derogatory) regarding use of the term "aspie".

Answer (score 25):

In the US, the [TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/special-procedures) has a [notification card](https://www.tsa.gov/sites/default/files/disability_notification_card_508.pdf) and

> You or your traveling companion may consult the TSA officer about the best way to relieve any concerns during the screening process.

The UK security process is not as clear, but https://www.gov.uk/airport-rights outlines the rights of disabled people at the airport. This [website](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/consumer/transport/transport/advice-for-disabled-travellers/rights-of-disabled-air-travellers-at-the-airport/) suggests

> Contact customer services at the airport if you need help to move through the airport from check-in, through security to the departure gate. You shouldn't be charged for this assistance.

I think the take home message is that you should let security know what is up and ask for reasonable accommodations.

Comment: That reminds me of the [Autipas](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autipas).

Answer (score 19):

I can't speak about other countries, but in the USA, contact TSA at the airport *ahead of time* and describe your issues. Most likely they will arrange for a TSA agent to escort you through security. You'll still have to do everything you would normally have to do (show ID, take off shoes, scan luggage, etc.), but the escort will bypass the lines and get you through as fast as possible. In your case, they may set you up at an unused scanner, with no one waiting behind you, so there is no pressure.

My son has autism, and waiting in line and getting through security was a huge challenge for us, for TSA, and everyone else in line. After one scary incident, TSA told us we could get an escort in the future. Now getting through security is simple and trouble-free, for everyone.

I would imagine that at most airports in Europe, you could do the same thing. Find out who handles security and call them *ahead of time*. Ahead of time means at least one day before. Don't wait until you get to the airport.

Comment: Specifically, to arrange this escort service in the US, you can [call TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/passenger-support) at (855) 787-2227. They ask that you call at least 72 hours in advance. In some cases, they can arrange for a passenger support specialist to [meet you at the checkpoint](https://www.tsa.gov/blog/2019/03/08/tsa-job-passenger-support-specialist) to help. That's someone you can talk to ahead of time to explain your needs, and they can do their best to accommodate that (in this case, the OP might have asked to try to minimize time away from their plush and keep it in sight).

Answer (score 8):

They will also ask you to take your hands out of your pockets when going through the scanner, so maybe the inside of your pocket is not the best place to keep a plushy? Maybe you can make something that becomes an "accessory" that you can wear on the outside, for example a string/cloth hanging from a beltloop?

From my many flight experiences, I've developed an automatic change of attitude when I get close to a security check. (They whole concept and experience is horrible, but as a passenger you can't change much about it) I make it into an **excerise of relaxation** and slowing down. Totally ignore all the people around you (both passengers and personell) and how they send out stress. You are in your own bubble of relaxation, and their moods won't influence you. Instead you can try to send out vibes of relaxation and smile at people.

Also I prepare while waiting in line by taking off all my metal items and putting them in the pockets of my jacket which I take off anyway. This removes all the hassle at the front part. At the end of the check I can put on my jacket, grab my bag and walk away in a smooth move if I want to. Both most often I put on my things extra slowly in order to claim my space and stay relaxed. If there isn't enough space for the other people coming behind me that is not my problem, but rather a bad design of the space, and then it's the personells problem.

Comment: Good answer. Come prepared and don't feel hurried by the rest. They do their thing, you do yours.

Comment: I actually put the things in my hand luggage, so that I don't fear them getting loose from the pockets.

Comment: I have zippers in my pockets. But if you don't have that, then yes a closed bag is a better idea.

Answer (score 6):

There are three things I'm going to suggest:

1. **Ask for assistance at check-in.** They are able to assist people with various disabilities, they may be willing to assist you. It is worth trying. People in both the Netherlands and the UK seem very nice and understanding, you get a chance.
2. **Try to get yourself eligible for the fast track.** The security at fast tracks usually deals with less people, less problematic people (the once with silver/golden cards travel a lot, and usually with little luggage; they behave well), and in general, they are more friendly.
3. This may work for you but may not. **You can take both your plush friends.** (I know this is difficult and takes a lot of space; have you tried having a 3rd, very small plush friend as your travel companion?) Put one on the belt and keep the other one with you. When the 1st one makes it to the other side, put the 2nd one on the belt, pass the scanner and grab the 1st one. This way, you are in close contact with at least one of them most of the time, it's basically only 5 seconds to walk through the frame.

Answer (score 3):

You could always check your luggage in to the hold, and collect it at the other end. If you limit what you carry to just the items you actually need during the flight (passport, boarding pass, plush seem like the minimum), then you will minimize the stress of going through security.

Consider taking disposable forms of entertainment / time killers on the actual plane e.g. a magazine instead of a laptop.

Comment: I dont think checking in a laptop is a good idea - or actually not even allowed, as it usually contains a Li-Ion-battery...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This may help others with similar problems, but not me, as @Gerhard pointed out. Besides, putting my laptop in the hold would make me even more uncomfortable.

Comment: @Gerhard Agreed. Checking in valuable items is a *terrible* idea. Quite apart from the issue of Li-ion batteries being forbidden, thefts from the security check are very rare but, on average, about 35 baggage handlers are fired every year in the US for stealing from passengers' luggage (source: [WJS](http://www.wsj.com/articles/new-tactics-in-the-fight-against-stolen-luggage-1407968449)). I don't see why the US would be atypical in this regard.

Comment: @DavidRicherby To suggest that it is a **terrible** idea is a very extreme statement. As you've said, it is very rare (it has never happened to me, or anyone I know), and is an insurable risk. I'm not saying there isn't some merit to your statement (although I've actually had someone walk off a plane with my luggage by mistake once, so it isn't without it's own risks). But a healthy dose of perspective is worth holding on to. There is probably a bigger risk of having your valuables stolen on your holiday, than on the plane, but it isn't a terrible idea to go on holiday.

Comment: @JBentley I agree that "is a _terrible_ idea" is an exaggeration but it was too late to edit the comment. :-( It's not a *good* idea.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is trying to get my ticket upgraded so that I'll have access to the Fast Track and Lounge.

This makes the journey a lot easier.

Comment: How do you do that? By paying extra? And would it be enough for people with severe autism?