# Passing through immigration with autism

Tags: customs-and-immigration, tips-and-tricks

**Inspired by**: [Passing through airport security with autism](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58653/passing-through-airport-security-with-autism)

Immigration officers are trained to assess a passenger's [personal impact and articulation skills](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93939/what-is-meant-by-personal-impact-and-articulation-skills-in-the-context-of-bor), in gauging if a person ought to be allowed entry.  If someone appears nervous, does not make eye contact, has trouble communicating, looks uncomfortable, and seems unwilling to engage in conversation, most immigration officers would consider this quite suspicious.  Yet, it strikes me that this may be *normal* behaviour for a person on the autistic spectrum.

How can a person with autism best navigate immigration?

Comment: @gdrt All tourists have to pass through immigration and customs!

Comment: Sorry, I thought the other question was already about customs. +1.

Comment: One might hazard a guess that part of the officers training would be to distinguish between those who have medical issues and those who are acting suspicious. But as no government will reveal exactly what they train their officials to look for, all answers will be guesses.

Comment: The spectrum of autism is too broad for a single answer. Please clarify your exact issue in more detail.